# How does economist.com implement their sticky header? jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, header, sticky

If you go to an article on The Economist website. For example:

> http://www.economist.com/node/17629757

When you scroll down the page past a certain point (either with the PAGEDOWN button or by incrementally scrolling with the DOWNARROW key), a red sticky header appears.

Is that jQuery?

How is that implemented?

Comment: looks like they are using jquery , do you want to achieve the same , its should be not a big deal to implement that , search for sticky footer , you can use the same for sticky header...

Comment: Did you try looking through the HTML & JS source of the page?

Comment: This is a good question - it came up in a Google search for 'javascript sticky header'. Why doesn't anyone upvote good questions on SOF anymore? Anyway, Jake, you've got an upvote.

Answer (score 3):

The Economist uses [Apture](http://www.apture.com/), a service which includes the sticky header and a few other features on the page. (The header has the ID "aptureD", so I started Googling.) If all you want is that exact header, you can just use their service.

Answer (score 3):

The content, while added via JavaScript is just [position](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#choose-position): fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Apture or make a custom sticky header. Look at [example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/lex_rwx/w4UdH/).

Comment: Very nice use of jsfiddle for the example - really helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve that: `position:fixed` and `position:absolute`.
The first one is very basic and you won't be able to get any sliding animation. The second one is what used in your example. Here is a good [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/creating-a-floating-html-menu-using-jquery-and-css/) with [demo](https://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/018_Floating_Menu/demo/dhtml_float_menu_final_nettut.html) and a [source](https://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/018_Floating_Menu/code-floating-menu.zip).