# javascript effect

Tags: javascript, html

i notice there's this functionality on 9gag.com. on the homepage, the 'Y u no signup' button is on the right. but as you scroll down, the button is hooked onto the header banner. how is this done?? this can be also seen on this very page whereby the yellow panel(similar Questions) on the right freeze when u scroll this page down. in facebook timeline, as you scroll down there will be a absolute div which appear on the top which contain options for timeline, now, status, photo, place and event.

r they using javascript or is this something new in html5??

Comment: Have you tried searching for it yourself? Try improving your search terms (Javascript effect really doesnt describe an element not moving when the user scrolls down), take more time and care in asking your questions to fix obvious typo's and accept old answers. Decent people put effort into answering your questions, least you can do is ask them properly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when the user scrolls down the computer checks for the amount scrolled.Let's say you scroll down with 50 px .The computer checks if the scroll distance is equal or bigger than 50.
If so then it will display that new Y u no Signup?!
and then if the scroll distance is smaller than 50 the top button simply isn't displayed anymore.

Comment: hi tks i managed to do it with ur help. i use javascript to check the scrollheight and change the <div> text with the help of css too

Answer (score 2):

No this is simple HTML, or rather CSS. Use `position: fixed;`. See - [here](http://davidwalsh.name/css-fixed-position). You can check [my site](http://cink.applegrew.com/) too for example.

Comment: Actually the effect on 9gag.com is achieved with javascript, it is not just postion:fixed because it starts out down the page a bit, detects any scrolling and then re-positions the button.

Comment: @Crisman Yes true, but that will be needed till it snaps into header. To maintain it there, `position: fixed` can be used.

Comment: hi all, i managed to resolve and i used both css and javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a near duplicate question: [How does economist.com implement their sticky header? jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360816/how-does-economist-com-implement-their-sticky-header-jquery)

The answer is that you use javascript to detect scrolling, and change the css of the div you want to move to position:fixed after a certain amount of scrolling.